# Fail to run the example in the OpenCV tutorial of Load Caffe framework models

Tags: opencv

I've tried the example in the opencv_contrib tutorial of dnn: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html

But it return two errors, I've search for hours and didn't get any solution. Does anyone could give me some help?

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (retval == 0) in cv::ocl::Kernel::set, file D:\opencv32\opencv\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line 3366
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (The following error occured while making forward() for layer "loss3/classifier": retval == 0) in cv::ocl::Kernel::set, file D:\opencv32\opencv\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line 3366
```